# Architecture Issue for handling large data from MySql Server

Tags: php, mysql, xml, json

I have 5 tables with millions of rows. Question is I need to create a menu and even extend more maybe in the future. The select Queries to this tables is the heart of my Website. Any one visiting my site would amount to a dozen of select queries to the server. What would be the best architecture design that could be implemented in this case?

1. Using indexing and caching.
2. Generating an XML or JSON which can be used by all the users without the need to query the db each time. [XML or JSON could be generated via a cron job, My rows wont change in every 5 minutes].

Or is there any other good solution to this? Even critiquing my ways i mentioned above is a valid answer.

PS: I would be happy not to invest in more server power if the solution could lie in a better Software Architecture.

Comment: It is far from clear that using JSON/XML/whatever to cache database server results is an improvement.  What are the nature of the queries:  complex joins?  massive aggregation? extensive results?  Are the results customized per user?

Comment: complex joins Yes. customized per user Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the APC user cache to store frequently used data but if your queries are customized per user, that might not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is indexing your tables correctly, use fields of type `int` to join your tables, set [query_cache_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html) to 512 MB (maybe more but this will be enough), use APC user cache. If you process quite big data with `for` loop instead of

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
```

do something like:

```
$count = count($arr);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
```

This is not a complete guide, but it's basics.

Comment: Better yet, avoid the for loop in php. If you can use foreach, it's generally faster.

Comment: @ElijahMadden it depends on given task. For example, `foreach ($arr as $key => $val) $arr[$key] .= 'something';` is slower than `$key = array_keys($arr); for ($i = 0; $i < $pre_calculated_size_of_key; $i++) $arr[$key[$i]] .= 'something';`

Comment: You're right (http://phpbench.com/ has some good info about this) but I've often wondered if the results might be different with: `foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) $val .= 'something';`. So far, I've been too lazy to do my own testing of this though.